# Using onclick event, how to match name with multiple status by drawing lines in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  
  data: {
    getQuestionAnswers: [
        {
        name: 'foo',
        checked: false,
        status: 'ok'
      },
      {
        name: 'bar',
        checked: false,
        status: 'notok'
      },
      {
        name: 'baz',
        checked: false,
        status: 'medium'
      },
            {
        name: 'oo',
        checked: false,
        status: 'medium'
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width:100%
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
.bcom {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
}
.container1 {
   width: 50px;
 }
 .container2 {
   width: calc(100% - 105px);
   padding: 8px 0;
   height: 30px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
 .h-line {
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
 }
.container3{
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 50px;
}


.point:hover {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
 <div class="bcom"
    v-for="(group, index) in getQuestionAnswers"
    :key="index + group.name"
    :group="group"
  >
  <div>
   <input type="checkbox" v-model="group.checked"/>
    {{ group.name }}
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
   <div class="h-line" v-if="group.checked"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type="checkbox"/> 
    {{ group.status }}
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Onclick of checkbox, how to add multiple lines from one point in Vuejs?

As seen in the image, On click of the checkbox, Based on the status, I need to match from one point to three multiple status. like "ok, notok, medium"

i have taken v-model in the checkbox,to check and perfome two way data binding But not sure....what to do further. Do I need to take computed property and write condition to check and draw three multiple lines???

Comment: I'm not clear about how you decide where a line should be drawn; but regardless, maybe add a line from everything to every other thing to the dom, then either hide selectively (either with v-show, v-if or with CSS or with hidden prop)?

Comment: Not sure if I understand completely. Why does Foo get match to all three ok, notok and medium?

Comment: Ok so when I click foo - shouldn't it only get linked to Ok? Since that's the status of foo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are som positioning issues here, but [this sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-67htlk?file=src/App.vue) should be enough for you to get it working:

template

```html
  <div id="demo" :ref="'plane'">
    <canvas :ref="'canvas'"></canvas>
    <div
      class="bcom"
      v-for="(group, index) in getQuestionAnswers"
      :key="index + group.name"
      :group="group"
    >
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          v-on:click="() => onToggleCheckbox(group)"
          v-model="group.checked"
          :ref="'checkbox_' + group.name"
        />
        <span>{{ group.name }}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>{{ group.status }}</span>
        <input type="checkbox" :ref="'status_' + group.name" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

script:

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    ctx: undefined,
    draw(begin, end, stroke = 'black', width = 1) {
      if (!this.ctx) {
        const canvas = this.$refs['canvas'];
        if (!canvas?.getContext) return;

        canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;

        this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      }

      if (stroke) {
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = stroke;
      }

      if (width) {
        this.ctx.lineWidth = width;
      }

      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.moveTo(...begin);
      this.ctx.lineTo(...end);
      this.ctx.stroke();
    },
    onToggleCheckbox(group) {
      const planeEl = this.$refs['plane'];
      const planeRect = planeEl.getBoundingClientRect();

      const fromEl = this.$refs['checkbox_' + group.name];
      const fromRect = fromEl.getBoundingClientRect();
      const from = {
        x: fromRect.right - planeRect.left,
        y: fromRect.top + fromRect.height / 2 - planeRect.top,
      };

      const toEl = this.$refs['status_' + group.name];
      const toRect = toEl.getBoundingClientRect();
      const to = {
        x: toRect.left - planeRect.left,
        y: toRect.top + toRect.height / 2 - planeRect.top,
      };

      console.log(planeRect, from, to);

      this.draw(
        Object.values(from),
        Object.values(to),
        group.checked ? 'white' : 'black',
        group.checked ? 3 : 2
      );
    },
    getQuestionAnswers: [
      {
        name: 'foo',
        checked: false,
        status: 'ok',
      },
      {
        name: 'bar',
        checked: false,
        status: 'notok',
      },
      {
        name: 'baz',
        checked: false,
        status: 'medium',
      },
      {
        name: 'oo',
        checked: false,
        status: 'medium',
      },
    ],
  }),
};
```

style

```css
body {
  background: #20262e;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#demo {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bcom {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

this only draws one line but you could easily add the others. I figured you might change your data schema to something like:

```
getQuestions() {
      {
        name: string,
        checked: boolean,
        statuses: [string...],
      },
getStatuses() {
      {
        name: string
      }
```

but not knowing about your requirements here, I decided to post the above before making further changes. (here is the sort of refactor I was referring to: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-yuvsxa )

### addressing first comment:

> in app.vue only there is one data called[((questions))], inside question we are looping and setting the status.

this is easy to address with a bit of preprocessing:

```
questionsAndStatusesMixed: // such as [{...question, ...statuses}],
questions: [],
statuses: [],
mounted() {
  const statusesSet = new Set()
  this.questionsAndStatusesMixed.forEach(item => {
    const question = {
        name: item.name,
        checked: item.checked,
        answer: item.status // is this the answer or .. these never made sense to me,
        statuses: this.statuses // assuming each question should admit all statuses/that is, draw a line to each
    }
    const status = {
      name: item.name
    }
    this.questions.push(question)
    statusesSet.add(status)
  })
  Array.from(statusesSet).forEach(item => this.statuses.push(item))
}
```

Comment: sharing data between child components is usually done with a single source of truth, such as vuex. you can traffic the data among the parent and child components using props but this is bad practice. You could also provide an id to each option expected to be there and then find it with document.querySelector, but this introduces knowledge about component b in component a. Im not sure how to advise you because your questions are compounding and varied. please accept this answer and read about state management such as vuex.

Comment: seems to be taken down .. you can always link to this question from that one

Comment: @Sundar I was curious what it would take to get the redraw fixed so I worked from yuor new verwsion this time; I think I now have this largely working as a prototype for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/live-demo-virtual-list-forked-e5idk